# Distribution of outer product of two uniform r.v.'s on ellipsoid

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, outer-product

Suppose $Z \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ and define $\widetilde{Z} \overset{\text{def}}{=}Z/\|Z\|_2$. Is there a closed-form distribution for $P \overset{\text{def}}{=} \widetilde{Z} \widetilde{Z}^\intercal$? I'm willing to accept just computing $\mathbb{E} P$.